# Writing style: how to distinguish between the estimators as random variables and estimates calculated from ONE experimental outcome

Tags: statistics, soft-question, hypothesis-testing

When writing down the procedure hypothesis tests, I try to follow the convention that upper case letters $X,Y$ represents random variables (RV) and small letters $x,y$ represents the outcome of ONE experiment, i.e., a sample. However, I find that I am having some difficulties doing this due to the lack of notation.

To give an example from two sample $t$-test:

> From the data given, the unbaised estimators $\hat\sigma^2_1=56.4$,  $\hat\sigma^2_2=53.4$. (Just an example, numbers are randomly given.) Therefore, the pooled estimate of the variance of samples (assuming the both samples have the same variance) is
>   $$s_p^2=\frac{(n_1-1)\hat\sigma^2_1+(n_2-1)\hat\sigma^2_2}{n_1+n_2-2}=54.0
> $$
>   The test statistic is
>   $$t=\frac{\bar y-\bar x}{s_p(1/n_1+1/n_2)^{1/2}}=1.24
> $$
>   Now, $(n_k-1)\hat\sigma^2_k/\sigma^2$ follows a $\chi^2$ distribution of freedom degree $n_k-1$, ... (to be continued)

Here I run into a problem. I already give $\sigma^2_1$ a **specific** value $56.4$, so I cannot really say that $(n_k-1)\hat\sigma^2_k/\sigma^2$ follows a $\chi^2$ distribution. I must replace $\sigma^2_k$ by an upper case letter, $\Sigma^2_k$, to distinguish between the value obtained from one experiment and the RV itself. However, I never see $\Sigma^2_k$ before - it looks very strange.

Let's continue.

> Let $\sigma$ be the common variance of $X$ and $Y$. Now, $(n_k-1)\hat\sigma^2_k/\sigma^2$ follows a $\chi^2$ distribution of freedom degree $n_k-1$, so $(n_1+n_2-2 )S_p^2 /\sigma^2$  follows a $\chi^2$ distribution of freedom degree $n_1+n_2-2$. Therefore we may conclude that
>   $$
> T=\frac{\bar Y-\bar X}{S_p(1/n_1+1/n_2)^{1/2}}
> $$
>   follows a student distribution of freedom degree $\nu=n_1+n_2-2$. We can now check the critical value from the table...

The rest should be no problem. For $X,Y,S_p$, capital letters are quite easy to use.

Question: What should I use for the "upper case" $\hat \sigma$? If I use $S$, then it might be confused with the moments.

Comment: Upper case/lower case are conventions only. If $\hat\sigma_1^2=\hat\sigma^2_1(X)$ is an estimator, then you can simply say observed value of $\hat\sigma_1^2$ is $\hat\sigma^2_1(x)=56.4$, which is the estimate.